# Using vectors to find cube vertices with 3 given points

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a question on my assignment that I have been stuck on for a while now. We're given **3 points** on the cube shown which we need to use to find all other coordinates on the cube.

[image: Two views of a cubical building, embedded at a slant into the ground; A, B, C, and D are marked as the corners of the roof of the building. A' is marked as the point along the edge of the cube from A down into the ground where it meets the ground.]

The three given points are:

- B = (2.7997, 22.3302, 11.9406)
- B' = (1.9651, 19.8699, 0)
- D =  (29.2866, 13.3456, 11.9406)

So far I have found **D'** by finding **B-B'** and then subtracting **B-B'** from **D**, but I am completely stumped on how to find the rest of the coordinates. How should I approach finding the other points?

Comment: Was there $B'$ before the edit? Maybe it is now $A'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B$ and $D$ together form the diagonal of the top face; $B'$ isn't the true corner of the cube but a point along the edge $BF$, where it crosses the plane $z=0$; the other four coordinates of the cube are actually below the ground.

In order to find $A$ and $C$ we'll need to figure out the plane that they're all in; this plane is normal to $BB'$, so we'll find that unit vector $N = \frac{B-B'}{|B-B'|}$.

$AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular to each other, and cross at the center of the square; we'll call that $X = \frac{B+D}{2}$.  We also need half-diagonal vector $M = |X - B|$.  Now, crossing $Y = N \times M$ we get a vector that is 1. in the plane and perpendicular to $BD$ (and thus parallel to $AC$) and has the length of $M$ (since $M$ and $N$ are perpendicular and $N$ is unit).  $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are now $A$ and $C$, but which order depends on your coordinate system.

Now, we need to find $E$ and its pals, to complete the cube, and $A'$ and its pals, to find the surface locations.

The length of an edge of the cube is $\ell = |A-B|$; $E$ is $\ell$ away from $A$ and in the direction $-N$, so $E = A -\ell N$.  Similarly $F = B - \ell N$, $G = C - \ell N$, and $H = D - \ell N$.

$A'$ and friends are a little bit less obvious.  I'll call $P = N / N_z$, so that it is 1 unit long when projected in the $z$ direction.  Now, $A' = A - PA_z$, etc.: $A_z$ says how high off the ground it is, so $PA_z$ is a vector that is exactly that tall but in the direction of $N$.